# JavaScript regexp - is there any alpha in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I just need to check if there any alpha in coming string.

I tried

```
str.search('/\w+/');
```

with diferent modifications. But it seems like I do smth wrong :(

Comment: Why do you have that single-quote character there?  As it is, that code will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, i missed closing single-quote in question. But it works without quotes! Thanks!

Comment: `'/\w+/'` is a string, not a regular expression.

Comment: Please correct the code in your question. It is misleading for others.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret your "any alpha" as meaning "at least one letter", in which case you can do this:

```
if(/[a-z]/i.test(str)) {
    // do something
}
```

Your current code has a syntax error in that you have a quote character before your regex literal, but even aside from that `\w` matches alphanumeric or underscore, i.e., letters or digits or `_`, so it could match on a string like `"123_"`.

If you wanted to check that the string had *only* alpha characters you could do:

```
if (/^[a-z]+$/i.test(str)) {
```

or test for any non-alpha but invert the result:

```
if (!/[^a-z]/i.test(str)) {
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one is that I need!

Answer (score 1):

When using regex in Javascript, you use either quotes (single or double) or `/` around it.

So, try this:

```
str.search('\\w+'); // Ending quote added
```

Or

```
str.search(/\w+/);
```

`\w` is equivalent to `A through Z`, `a through z`, `0 through 9` or `_` though...